# JFace TreeView remove item

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, swt, jface

I have a treeView in my wizard application. Whenever i add or remove an object from my model , calling the update or refresh methods works as expected. What i want is , when i press a certain check button, two things may happen: If the new selection is false(unchecked) , i want to remove the treeView items , so they wont show in my UI, and when the new selection is true(checked) , i want to add the previously removed items (i have them stored in my application), so they can show up again. So i added this listener to my button :

```
    oIsAuthorizableResourceButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            bIsResourceAuthorizable[intSelectedResourceIndex] = oIsAuthorizableResourceButton.getSelection();
            //recursiveSetEnabled(grpPolicySetConfiguration,oIsAuthorizableResourceButton.getSelection());
            if(!bIsResourceAuthorizable[intSelectedResourceIndex]){
                System.out.println("Remove : " + oSelectedPolicySet.getHasResourceAccessPolicy().size());
                oTreeViewer.remove(oSelectedPolicySet.getHasResourceAccessPolicy().toArray());
                oTreeViewer.refresh(oSelectedPolicySet);
                oTreeViewer.refresh();
            }else{
                System.out.println("Add : " + oSelectedPolicySet.getHasResourceAccessPolicy().size());
                oTreeViewer.add(oSelectedPolicySet, oSelectedPolicySet.getHasResourceAccessPolicy().toArray());
                oTreeViewer.refresh(oSelectedPolicySet);
                oTreeViewer.refresh();
            }
        }
```

Well this code does absolutely nothing.Any help appreciated.

Comment: Curious, instead of removing the specific nodes, can't you just 'hide' them? If I recall you can make a node visible or not.

Comment: Well....if you build a class for it: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/InvisibleNodeTreeExample.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a Viewer Filter, then add and remove it from your viewer: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-TreeViewer/TreeViewerArticle.htm . What it filters, and whether it even cares about a specific property, is your choice.

Comment: Well i feel stupid , didn't know about filters. I guess this is my answer, but can you please tell me (possibly) why the above example doesn't work? I'm kinda new to this kind of programming, so i'm not very familiar with the frameworks.

Comment: Whenever you call refresh(), you are resetting the viewer, or part of the viewer, so that it again shows whatever objects your content provider gave it, filtered according to the Viewer Filters. That returned group of objects is usually just a small step away from your actual model, from which you're not adding or removing anything.